# WebCola Missing documentation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webcola

I'm trying to use WebCola http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/ but I can't find a link to the real documentation. The website seems to have only a few examples and some (apparently) auto-generated docs which are not really useful for anything at all. It's a very cool library so I'm sure there's some very cool documentation somewhere. Can anyone share the link?

Comment: Looks like it's all on Github wiki https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola/wiki

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola

Look at here, i think this will help